# Converting existing content to a different locale

Tags: localization

I am in the process of building my first multilingual Craft site.

The site will have two languages:

- English (default)
- Spanish

When setting up the site, I chose `U.S. English` and `Spanish - United States` as the respective locales.

I am now thinking it might be better to keep the languages less specific to the United States and would like to switch the two to `English` and `Spanish`.

My question is if it is possible to do this without losing any content that has already been entered under both `U.S. English` and `Spanish - United States`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to edit a locale from the CP, which means you have to edit it directly in your db.

**Edit locale:**

```sql
UPDATE craft_locales SET locale = 'en' WHERE locale = 'en_us';
```

**Edit elements:**

Each element (entries, assets, users, etc.) which can be translated has a `locale`-column:

```sql
UPDATE craft_categorygroups_i18n SET locale = 'en' WHERE locale = 'en_us';
UPDATE craft_content             SET locale = 'en' WHERE locale = 'en_us';
UPDATE craft_elements_i18n       SET locale = 'en' WHERE locale = 'en_us';
UPDATE craft_entryversions       SET locale = 'en' WHERE locale = 'en_us';
UPDATE craft_sections_i18n       SET locale = 'en' WHERE locale = 'en_us';
```

**Edit permissions:**

```sql
UPDATE craft_userpermissions SET name = 'editlocale:en' WHERE name = 'editlocale:en_us';
```

**Check:**

To be sure you've got them all do a sql search for `en_us`.

Comment: Awesome. This worked perfectly. I was able to update all `en_us` entries to `en` and `es_us` entries to `es`. Thanks!